# difference between version r0.11 and r0.9

Tags: tensorflow

The latest version of Tensorflow is `r0.11`, I am using `0.9.0`. Before updating the Tensorflow to the latest version, I would like to know whether there are any major changes for the Tensorflow, which can cause the original code fail to compile/run.

Answer (score 1):

There are various API changes, mostly documented in [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md). One undocumented change I ran into was that custom variable initializers must now have a `partition_info` keyword argument in the constructor.

There are also some numeric changes. IE, we have a model which trains on 0.9, doesn't train on 0.10, again trains on 0.11. These are usually undocumented/unintended and you just have to run and see.